# Is there opportunity to override implementation of NoSonarFilter

Tags: sonarqube

During creation a custom plugin I need to implement Sensor interface where I have an access to NoSonarFilter.
I wonder whether I can override the provided implementation of NoSonarFilter? And if I can than how.

Comment: Why would you want to override the default implementation? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NoSonarFilter` is a special implementation of an `IssueFilter`. If it doesn't fit your needs, then you can simply create a new extension and implements `IssueFilter`.